# tensorflowのresnetでimportエラー

Tags: python, python3, tensorflow

画像認識の評判の良いモデルとしてresnetがあっります。
それをgithubからクローンして実行しようとしたら、次のエラーメッセージがでました。

```
ImportError: No module named 'official'
```

ソースコードには次のimport文があります。

```
import tensorflow as tf  # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order

from official.mnist import dataset
from official.utils.arg_parsers import parsers
from official.utils.logs import hooks_helper
from official.utils.misc import model_helpers
```

つまり、officialというモジュールがないということだと思われますが、
そのモジュールそのものをインストールしようとしてもできません。
そもそもofficialというモジュールはどうやってインストールするのでしょうか。
大変申し訳ありませんが、どなたかお分かりの方がおりましたら、教えて下さい。

それでは、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

[TensorFlow Models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models)には、サンプルのためか開発中のためかはわかりませんが、`setup.py`スクリプトがありません。それで、そのままではツールを使ったインストールはできず、自分で書いたモジュールと同じ扱いになります。

次の行以下の`import`文を有効にするためには、`models`ディレクトリ以外にプログラムを配置する場合には、適切にディレクトリを書くようにするか、

```
from official.mnist import dataset
```

次のように環境変数`PYTHONPATH`に`models`ディレクトリを追加します。

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/models
```

次に、officialに必要な依存パッケージをインストールします。`official`ディレクトリに`requirements.txt`があるので以下のような感じで`pip`でインストールできます。

```
pip3 install -r official/requirements.txt
```